# Moving data between PostgreSQL databases respecting conflicting keys

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, foreign-keys

### Situation

I have a 2 databases which were in one time direct copies of each other but now they contain new different data.

### What do I want to do

I want to move data from database "SOURCE" to database "TARGET" but the problem is that the tables use auto-incremented keys, and since both databases are used at the same time, a lot of the IDs are already taken up in TARGET so I cannot just identity insert the data coming from SOURCE.

But in theory we could just not use identity insert at all and let the database take care of assigning new IDs.

What makes it harder is that we have like 50 tables where each of them is connected by foreign keys. Clearly the foreign keys will also have to be changed else they will no longer reference the correct thing.

Let's see a very simplified example:

```
table Human {
  id integer NOT NULL PK AutoIncremented
  name varchar NOT NULL
  parentId integer NULL FK -> Human.id 
}

table Pet {
  id integer NOT NULL PK AutoIncremented
  name varchar NOT NULL
  ownerId integer NOT NULL FK -> Human.id 
}

SOURCE Human
Id      name      parentId
==========================
1       Aron      null
2       Bert      1
3       Anna      2

SOURCE Pet
Id      name      ownerId
==========================
1       Frankie   1
2       Doggo     2    

TARGET Human
Id      name      parentId
==========================
1       Armin      null
2       Cecil     1

TARGET Pet
Id      name      ownerId
==========================
1       Gatto     2
```

Let's say I want to move Aron, Bert, Anna, Frankie and Doggo to the TARGET database.

But if we directly try to insert them with not caring about original ids, the foreign keys will be garbled:

```
TARGET Human
Id      name      parentId
==========================
1       Armin     null
2       Cecil     1
3       Aron      null
4       Bert      1
5       Anna      2

TARGET Pet
Id      name      ownerId
==========================
1       Gatto     2 
2       Frankie   1
3       Doggo     2
```

The father of Anna is Cecil and the Owner of Doggo is Cecil also instead of Bert. The parent of Bert is Armin instead of Aron.

How I want it to look is:

```
TARGET Human
Id      name      parentId
==========================
1       Armin     null
2       Cecil     1
3       Aron      null
4       Bert      3
5       Anna      4

TARGET Pet
Id      name      ownerId
==========================
1       Gatto     2 
2       Frankie   3
3       Doggo     4
```

Imagine having like 50 similar tables with 1000 of lines, so we will have to automate the solution.

### Questions

Is there a specific tool I can utilize?

Is there some simple SQL logic to precisely do that?

Do I need to roll my own software to do this (e.g. a service that connects to both databases, read everything in EF with including all relations, and save it to the other DB)? I fear that there are too many gotchas and it is time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific tool? Not as far as I know.  
Is there some simple SQL? Not exactly simple but not all that complex either.  
Do you need to roll own?  Maybe, depends on if you think you use the SQL (balow).

I would guess there is no direct path, the problem being as you note, getting the FK values reassigned. The following adds a column to all the tables, which can be used to span the across the tables. For this I would use a uuid. Then with that you can copy from one table set to the other except for the FK. After copying you can join on the uuid to complete the FKs.

```
-- establish a reference field unique across databases. 
 alter table target_human add sync_id uuid default gen_random_uuid ();
 alter table target_pet   add sync_id uuid default gen_random_uuid ();
 alter table source_human add sync_id uuid default gen_random_uuid ();
 alter table source_pet   add sync_id uuid default gen_random_uuid ();  
 
--- copy table 2 to table 1 except parent_id 
 insert into target_human(name,sync_id)
   select name, sync_id 
     from source_human;
 
-- update parent id in table to prior parent in table 2 reasigning parent  
with conv (sync_parent, sync_child, new_parent) as 
     ( select h2p.sync_id sync_parent, h2c.sync_id sync_child, h1.id new_parent
         from source_human h2c
         join source_human h2p on h2c.parentid = h2p.id
         join target_human h1  on h1.sync_id = h2p.sync_id 
     ) 
update target_human  h1
   set parentid = c.new_parent
  from conv c 
 where h1.sync_id = c.sync_child;
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
alter table target_pet alter column ownerId drop not null; 

insert into target_pet(name, sync_id) 
  select name, sync_id 
    from source_pet ;
    
with conv ( sync_pet,new_owner) as 
     ( select p2.sync_id, h1.id 
         from source_pet p2 
         join source_human h2  on p2.ownerid = h2.id
         join target_human h1  on h2.sync_id = h1.sync_id
     )  
update target_pet  p1
   set ownerid = c.new_owner 
  from conv c 
 where p1.sync_id = c.sync_pet; 
 
alter table target_pet alter column ownerId set not null;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f446c30650f088c12d6d1d6ca6984a03). You now reverse the source and target table definitions to complete the other side of the sync. You can then drop the uuid columns if so desired. But you may want to keep them. If you have gotten them out of sync, you will do so again. You could even go a step further and make the UUID your PK/FK and then just copy the data, the keys will remain correct, but that might involve updating the apps to the revised DB structure.  This does not address communication across databases, but I assume you already have that handled. You will need to repeat for each set, perhaps you can write a script to generate them. Further, I would guess there are fewer gotchas and less time consuming than rolling your own. This is basically 5 queries per table set you have, but to clean-up the current mess, 500 queries is not that much;